# MacMini 2018 is slow to wake after sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, mojave

I have Mac mini 2018 with Mojave 10.14.3 and external display LG 27UK600 connected via hdmi 2.0 cable. When i put my mac to sleep, then wake it after  5 minutes, it takes like 60 seconds to wake it up. When i press any key on the keyboard monitor is kinda wakes up, but then goes black again, only after this it actually wakes up, but mac itself is awaken very quick.

What might be a culprit here?

Comment: I also have a 4K LG monitor (slightly different model from yours) connected to a Mac mini 2018 (purchased in 2020 June). After long time sleep the monitor doesn't wake up at all, also after complete powerdown-powerup cycle the same thing happens, the monitor lights up but goes black after a few seconds and stays black. I have to reset NVRAM for it to fix itself (EACH time after power down). Somehow it doesn't happen with the family non-4K HDMI TV set. I've tried connecting both HDMI and USB-C to the monitor but the problem persists. I have no mice or anything connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was on MM's hdmi port, i switched to usb-c > DP and no more issues. Though it takes like 5 seconds to show up the picture, but it's acceptable, it's not 60 seconds.

I have no idea if Apple gonna fix this soon. But i have no purpose to use HDMI at all.

Comment: That's strange that the HDMi port takes so much time. Is your display 4k / 5k?

Comment: yeah, it's 4K. This bug still present to this day.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac Mini 2018 I bought early 2020.  Initially I had the slow wake problem but when I upgraded from a generic wired mouse to Bluetooth Apple magic mouse that problem went away and has not returned. I just tap the keyboard and within a few seconds it's back.

Comment: It doesn't matter, i have magic keyboard 2 / magic trackpad 2, or any 3rd party keyboard. Anyway i switched to an iMac, it's much better, no issues.